# Fortran90: Scripting of Standard In not working as expected

Tags: unix, fortran, fortran90

Working with Fortran90 in Unix...

I have a programme which needs to read in the input parameters from a file "`input-deck.par`". This filename is currently hard-coded but I want to run a number of runs using different input-deck files (`input-deck01.par`, `input-deck02.par`, `input-deck03.par` etc.) so I've set-up the code to do a simple "`read(*,*) inpfile`" to allow the user to input the name of this file directly on run-time with a view to scripting this later.

This works fine interactively. If I execute the programme it asks for the file name, you type it in and the filename is accepted, the file is opened and the programme picks up the parameters from that file.

The issue lies in scripting this. I've tried scripting using the "`<`" pipe command so:

```
myprog.e < input-deck01.par
```

But I get an error saying:

```
Fortran runtime error: Cannot open file '----------------': No such file or directory
```

If I print the filename right after the input line, it prints that the filename is '`----------------`' (I initialise the variable as having 16 characters hence the 16 hyphens I think)

It seems like the "`<`" pipe is not passing the keyboard input in correctly. I've tried with spaces and quotes around the filename (various combinations) but the errors are the same.

Can anyone help?

(Please be gentle- this is my first post on SO and Fortran is not my primary language....)

Comment: If I understand your description correct, your program expects to read the *name* of the input file from `stdin`, not the file's contents. Try `echo 'input-deck01.par' | myprog.e`. `<` is input redirection, not a pipe. Is `----------------` the first line of the file `input-deck01.par`?

Comment: You arent using the correct piping syntax. Your cmdline takes a file input-deck01.par and sends all the lines in the file as though typed in the console. What you want(I think off the top of my head, cant test right now) is echo 'input-deck01.par' | myprog.e

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, the file starts with "----------". I changed that first line to some random string and it's reproduced in the error so it is indeed reading the contents when I want the filename to be entered.

Trying the actual, proper pipe command suggested works nicely....thank you, both!

Answer (score 0):

Fortran has the ability to read the command line arguments.  A simple example is

```
program foo

  implicit none

  character(len=80) name
  logical available
  integer fd

  if (command_argument_count() == 1) then
     call get_command_argument(1, name)
  else
     call usage
  end if

  inquire(file=name, exist=available)
  if (.not. available) then
     call usage
  end if

  open(newunit=fd, file=name, status='old')

  ! Read file

  contains
     subroutine usage
        write(*,'(A)') 'Usage: foo filename'
        write(*,'(A)') '       filename --> file containing input info'
        stop
     end subroutine usage
end program foo
```

Instead of piping the file into the executable you simply do

```
% foo input.txt
```

Comment: Well, if you like the solution, could you click the 'This answer is useful' button.